# MongoDB : find all entries with one key

Tags: mongodb, find

I am trying to use mongoDB on a new project.

I have this documents in my database :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ID"), "local" : { "rank" : "null", "password" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "EMAIL" }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ID"), "local" : { "rank" : "admin", "password" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "EMAIL" }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("ID"), "local" : { "rank" : "null", "password" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "EMAIL" }, "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to find all documents with a null rank.

So I test :

```
db.users.find({local:{rank:"null"}})
```

But it doesn't work.

If I test with the command :

```
db.users.find({"local":{ "rank" : "null", "password" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "EMAIL" }})
```

It works. Why it doesn't work with the first command ?

Comment: Both comparisons you are doing against document object. The second one works because you are comparing against the document `local`. To compare specific field inside the document you have to use dot notation. Try `db.users.find({"local.rank":"null"})`.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me go ahead and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both comparisons you are doing against document. The second one works it matches document `local`.

To compare specific field inside the document you have to use dot notation.

```
 db.users.find({"local.rank":"null"}).
```

More about how to query embedded  document. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents